# matlab function not working surprisingly

Tags: matlab

I have created this function :

```
function Calcul_Constantes ( xBin1 , xTin1 , xHin1 )
% computes global variables that change depending on the circumstances

global v rhoc K1v K2v xBin xTin xHin cBin cTin cHin;

xBin=xBin1;
xTin=xTin1;
xHin=xHin1;
rhoc = 0.02777*(2.106*xHin+78.12*xBin)*(6.935*xHin+23.15*xBin);
K1v=0.6*rhoc/175;
K2v=(2.70803*10^-4+7.5*10^-4*v*rhoc)/175;
cBin=0.02777*xBin;
cTin=0.02777*xTin;
cHin=0.02777*xHin;
end
```

and when I do test in my main script :

```
Calcul_Constantes(0,0,1);
xBin
xHin
```

the following error occures:

> Error using Calcul_Constantes
>   Too many input arguments.
>   Error in Mercredi15_main (line 48)
>   Calcul_Constantes(0,0,1);

I'd be grateful for any help, I really can't see what does not work

Comment: Really? but it worked in my machine?

Comment: @MimSaad I still tried and it still shows the same error?! ;-(

Comment: I guess it has something to do with main  Mercredi15_main.m , This is what i'd type " global xBin
global xHin
Calcul_Constantes(0,0,1);"

Comment: @MimSaad Do you have any idea of the cause of my error. It's really annoying !

Comment: @MimSaad Thanks for your answer, actually xBin and xHin are defined as global variables at the top of Mercredi15_main...

Comment: Probably there is another Calcul_Constantes function somewhere else.

Comment: The scope of variable xBin is global. Changes to its value might span multiple workspace. @MimSaad That's the warning I have for xBin. Do you think it could explain the error?

Comment: no I've tested it, Are you sure you didn't save another version of Calcul_Constantes function somewhere else, try this, define a new function like Calcul_Constantes_2 with the same code of Calcul_Constantes and test it, if it works then you surely have two functions with the same name.

Comment: "type " which Calcul_Constantes

Comment: @MimSaad Indeed, I had an other version of Calcul_Constantes in the MATLAB folder! I deleted it and now, it displays 0 and 1! ...however I have other errors I will look at this afternoon after classes. :-/ Great thanks anyway!

Comment: is this correct syntax? I work usually work with something like this  function [output] = Calcul_Constantes( xBin1 , xTin1 , xHin1 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably there is another Calcul_Constantes function somewhere else. You might have saved another version of Calcul_Constantes function somewhere.
In command line type :

```
which Calcul_Constantes
```

and check if the return directory and .m file is the which you are trying to use. Rename or delete the wrong function.